# Firebase - Values to Group in Android App

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can anyone help me please?

I have app working with Realtime Firebase. But have problem with retrive data to ListView.
What I have.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUn0H.jpg)

[needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZlm7.jpg)

Have 4 types of groups with same and different values.
I need get same types from all values with group name, and list only that values as group.

- I have 30 records, if I list all values from group, get 10 values with ?cars, 10 values with flowers etc... :(

  ```
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(requireContext(), myDataList);
    listViewGroup.setAdapter(adapter);

    mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        double totalSum = 0.00;

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //String myData = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyData.class).toString();
                //myDataList.add(myData);

                //String myGroup = dataSnapshot.child("group").getValue().toString();
                //String myValue = dataSnapshot.child("groupValue").getValue().toString();
                //Float sumValue = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(myValue));
                //totalSum += sumValue;

                //if (totalSum == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
                    //txt_ValueTotal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6B8E23"));
                    //txt_ValueTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(totalSum * 100) / 100));
                //}
                //else {
                    //txt_ValueTotal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    //txt_ValueTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(totalSum * 100) / 100));
                //}


            }
        }
  ```

Please dont look on slash and name of variables, code is "suspended", but worked.
And sorry for my bad english, is not my native language.

EDIT:

> I have name of groups in Spinner, and Array resource, is possible get group names from array and create it, as array in DataSnapshot?
> I did not have to write manulay, if I add new item to Array(Resources)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not definitely a SQL that you can achieve a result what you needed in the picture you given but you can achieve it in front end like this

```
Int flowers=0;
Int Cars=0;

for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
     String myGroup = dataSnapshot.child("group").getValue().toString();
     String myValue = dataSnapshot.child("groupValue").getValue().toString();

     if(myGroup.Equals("Flowers"){
          flowers += Integer.parseInt(myValue); //parse to Int needed
     }else if(myGroup.Equals("")){

     }else{}//continue
}
```